# 'Safe' struct to JSON marshalling in Go

Tags: json, serialization, go

Is there a way to marshall a struct to JSON that skips any fields that can not be serialised?

E.G. if I marshal

```
type aStruct struct {
  request *http.Request
  name    string
}
```

the JSON representation of

```
type aStruct struct {
  name    string
}
```

would result?

By 'fields that can not be serialised' I mean any field that would cause json.Marshal(..) to return an 'error serializing json: unsupported type' error.  Having a look through the json package now with a mind to create another Marshal function that will skip a field it fails to serialise rather than abort and return the error.

==== UPDATE ====

I have created this https://github.com/myles-mcdonnell/jsonx which satisfies my use case.  At first I thought this is a terrible way to extend the base json package (it's a copy from 1.6.2 with new behaviour added) but the consensus among my colleagues is that this is the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: What is your definition of "not be serialised"? Circular data structures are problematic, channels are basically impossible, interface values might by tricky. It really depends on what you consider serialisable (and in which form).

Comment: I don't get the question at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: please see updated Q.

Comment: @Ainar-G I would like to be able to serialise any structure to json. Where the structure has field that can not be serialised it is simply ignored rather than causing the json.Marshal function to terminate the serialisation process and return an error.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell won't making the field unexported or using the `json:"-"` struct tag solve that?

Comment: @Ainar-G yes it would, but I don't define the types I'm trying to serialise (some are in fact auto generated by go-swagger) so that's not an option One technique that works is to copy the type instance and set all non serialisable fields to null, but that in my scenario would be laborious so I'm looking for a marshaller that just skips fields it can't serialise.